# Using Drop Downs with Text Fields in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that is using Bootstrap 3. I want to allow a user to dynamically convert between pounds and kilograms. I want to default to pounds. When a user chooses another option, I want the text of action to be the text of the selected option. I'm not sure how to do this. Currently, I have the following:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span>  
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Pounds</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kilograms</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I suspect I need to use onclick for the Pounds and Kilograms options. However, I'm not sure how to get the drop-down text to actually be the option instead of always saying "Action"

Comment: If you don't want to navigate away from the page, a `select` input element is probably more suitable. The fact that `dropdown` expects links in its menu tells you that it's designed for navigating away from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess there should be an easy way, but I didn't find it on the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns).

Meanwhile, as you said, you could use some jQuery/JavaScript to update the value of the button using the `onclick` event:

```
$(".input-group-btn .dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function() {

    // go up to the li, ul, and div, and then find the button (a bit "hacky", I know)
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".dropdown-toggle").html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret">');

});
```

You can see it working with your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/uvkcoybL/